# Unable to spot an SQL syntax error in the following functions : Causing an exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I keep getting the following error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near '= 3' at line 1
```

I went through my entire code and there are only 2 SQL functions which are being called at this point of time, capable of causing this error:

1. Read

   ```
   public void Read (String userName) /*have checked validity*/
   try {
       con = getConnection();

       PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + 
                                 tableName + 
                                " WHERE userName=?");

           pstmt.setString(1,userName);

       ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

       User user;
       PrintQuery(rs);
       rs.close();
       pstmt.close();
       releaseConnection(con);
       return user;

   }
   ```
2. GetItem

   ```
    public void getItem(int userid) /*have checked validity*/
    try {
       con = getConnection();

       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

       PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " 
                                 + tableName +"WHERE UserId=?");
       pstmt.setInt(1,userid);
       rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
       PrintQuery(rs);
       stmt.close();
       releaseConnection(con);

   }
   ```

I am stuck with these for hours now and I am not able to resolve it. I have double checked to see if these arguments are null etc. They are not. In fact they are all nicely present in the database. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Any help will  be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the error is on `GetName` because you lack an extra space during the concatenation between the tableName and the `WHERE` clause

```
+ tableName +" WHERE UserId=?");
           // ^ add extra space here
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem for which I spent like a solid 2 hours :(